# beautifulsoup python doesnt find what i am looking for

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So i am trying to extract the text in the grand-final section (the winner team name)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QPqI.png

my problem is that the text that im looking to extract isnt found by soup, it only finds up to (class="sgg2h1cC DEPRECATED_bootstrap_container undefined native-scroll dragscroll") but as you can see here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nEyH.png there is more.

here is my code, can someone explain how i would get the info im looking for? also im pretty new to webscraping

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://smash.gg/tournament/revolve-oceania-2v2-finale/event/revolve-oceania-2v2-finale-event/brackets/841267/1343704'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find(id="app_feature_canvas")
a = results.find_all('div', class_="regionWrapper-APP_TOURNAMENT_PAGE-FeatureCanvas")
print()
for b in a:
    c = b.find('div', class_="page-section page-section-grey")
    print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you see in your inspector is not the same as what you get when you use `requests`. Instead of using the dev console, view the page source.

Those parts of the page are generated by JavaScript, thus, will not appear when you request the page via `requests`.

```py
URL = 'https://smash.gg/tournament/revolve-oceania-2v2-finale/event/revolve-oceania-2v2-finale-event/brackets/841267/1343704'
page = requests.get(URL)
print(page.text)  # notice this is nothing like what you see in the inspector
```

To get javascript execution, consider using `selenium` instead of requests.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
html = driver.page_source  # DOM with JavaScript execution complete
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
# ... go from here
```

Alternatively, there may be enough information in the page source to get what you're looking for. Notice there's a lot of JSON in the page source with various info that, presumably, may be used by the JS to populate those elements.

Alternatively still, you can also copy/paste from the DOM browser in your inspector. (right-click the html element and click "copy outer html")

```py
html = pyperclip.paste()  # put contents of the clipboard into a variable
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
results = soup.find(id="app_feature_canvas")
a = results.find_all('div', class_="regionWrapper-APP_TOURNAMENT_PAGE-FeatureCanvas")
print()
for b in a:
    c = b.find('div', class_="page-section page-section-grey")
    print(c)
```

And this works :-)

Comment: but i want it to be automatic not copy and paste

Comment: In which case, use selenium or one of the other methods mentioned.

Comment: when you say "Notice there's a lot of JSON" i dont see any JSON

Comment: i dont really get it

Comment: around line 4700 I see [a ton of JSON](https://imgur.com/a/8x260DG). Scanning it, it seems to include things like usernames, placements, and more.